# flexbox displaying sub-div at the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is what I want to do:

[image: screenshot]

I have the brown part separately at the top as a `div`. Then the other colors  in a `content` `div`.

I don't understand how to bring the blue part at the top for < 768px since it is inside the `content` `div` .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .container{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .aquablue{
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #B0C4DE;
      order: 1;
    }
    .brownC{
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #663300;
    }
    .yellowC{
      padding: 50px;
      background-color:  #FFCC00;
      order: 3;
    }
    .greenC{
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      order: 4;
    }
    .blueC{
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #336699;
      order: 5;
    }
    @media(min-width: 768px){
      .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .content{
        display: flex;
        order: 2;
      }
      .left{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .right{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .brownC{
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #663300;
        width: 100%;
        order: 1;
      }
      .yellowC{
        padding: 50px;
        background-color:  #FFCC00;
      }
      .greenC{
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #00FF00;
      }
      .blueC{
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #336699;
      }
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="brownC"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left">  
          <div class="aquablue"></div>
          <div class="yellowC"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right"> 
          <div class="greenC"></div>
          <div class="blueC"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With that current structure I can only think of a js-solution. That is with the assumption that your aquablue is dynamic height as it seems as a content container?

Comment: @Dejan.S yea. what is the js solution?

Comment: this could probably be done but then you would change your structure. I'll post js in a minute

Comment: With the HTML you have you won't be able to do exactly that. You would need to alter your HTML a bit to make it workable.

Comment: @iLiveInAPineappleUnderTheSea What i will suggest is you don't need to add any js code for it, css will work very well  because of many reasons majorly - It's not a good practice, Js will take much time to load your page.
You can shuffle your  div's any way with a help of 
[Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: @Jhecht. alter how?

Comment: @iLiveInAPineappleUnderTheSea posted pure css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure css you can use this solution. What you do is to remove your "structual divs", on your `.container` is to add `flex: row;` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, then give your elements the width they should be, as in this case was `width: 100%;` for `.brownC` and `width: 50%;` for the rest. Does it make sense?

Check the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3fxszt0r/1)

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.aquablue {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #B0C4DE;
  order: 1;
}

.brownC {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #663300;
  order: 2;
}

.yellowC {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  order: 3;
}

.greenC {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  order: 4;
}

.blueC {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #336699;
  order: 5;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .brownC {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .aquablue {
    order: 2;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .yellowC {
    order: 4;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .greenC {
    order: 3;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .blueC {
    order: 5;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="brownC">

  </div>
  <div class="aquablue">

  </div>

  <div class="yellowC">

  </div>
  <div class="greenC">

  </div>
  <div class="blueC">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I am new to designing and this is the first time i'm using flex. can you tell me where i can find more practise templates like the one in my question?

Comment: I'm not sure about practise templates but css-tricks have a awesome extensive guide to flexbox, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the move the elements using `jQuery` on window `resize` event.

JS FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/pdr8qyut/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
            jQuery(".aquablue").after(jQuery(".brownC"));
        }else{
            jQuery(".content").before(jQuery(".brownC"));
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: if you give a js solution it's only fair that you make it with debounce so it's not taxing the performance.